# Degrees of Freedom for Linear Combination of Variables

Tags: normal-distribution, linear, degrees-of-freedom, t-distribution

I have three mean estimates, all from variables assumed to follow a Normal distribution. The following is a mock example.

x1 is estimated at 4, with a standard error of 5 and 6 degrees of freedom
x2 is estimated at 6, with a standard error of 4 and 6 degrees of freedom
x3 is estimated at 7, with a standard error of 3 and 6 degrees of freedom

What would be the degrees of freedom attached to (x1+x2+x3) ?

Comment: This depends on the dependence between the three xs.

Comment: How are the estimates made and what exactly do you mean by "degrees of freedom" of such an estimate?  (Estimates usually don't have anything known as a "degree of freedom," but often their *standard errors* do--and even then the meaning of d.f. varies with how the estimate is made.)

Comment: To @RichardHardy: They are independent, I should have stated that.

Comment: To @whuber: Those are the DFs attached to the standard errors. They have been estimated using maximum likelihood. If a parameter X follows a normal distribution, it's maximum likelihood estimate follows a T distribution with N-1 degrees of freedom due to the uncertainty on the variance estimate. Those are the degrees of freedom I'm referring to.

Comment: @PerrySun, please edit the post to include the additional information from the comments.

Comment: The MLE doesn't follow a Student $t$ distribution: it follows a *Normal* distribution, because it is a linear combination of the data (namely, their mean).  However, a statistic used for testing the mean--namely, the ratio of the estimate to its standard error--follows a *multiple* of the Student $t$ distribution.  If you're not accounting correctly for these facts, then any consideration of degrees of freedom is probably going to be irrelevant.